# Python reverse tcp exe stops

Tags: python-3.x

Hi everyone I'm making a tcp reverse shell with python when I convert it to a .exe file with this command:
`pyinstaller --onefile -w tcp_reverse_shell_client.py`
but when I enter my command from the server it stops no crash no error
here is the server code:
https://hatebin.com/vkbbruqogc
Client code:
https://hatebin.com/aefmuyghjh

Answer (score 0):

it's because I had to import json module with the hidden import so the command will be

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --hidden-import json tcp_reverse_shell_client.py
```